# jQuery: How can we implement if...else logic and call function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and so don't mind this question if it sounds stupid but here is something that I am trying to do :

I have 3 functions like:

```
AddToCart Function which adds item to the shopping cart:
//offer_id is the offer which we are trying to add to cart. 
    addToCart: function(offer_id)
    {
    },


RemoveFromCart which removes data from the cart
//target is link clicked and event is the click event. 
    removeFromCart: function(target, event)
    {
    },

Get the current state of the cart   
//return string which represents current state of cart. 
    getCartItems: function()
    {
    }
```

Now I am trying to do 3 things:

1. if there is no `content` in cart 
   and `addToCart` is called than `some action`, so basically here we need to check the current state of cart and that is obtained by calling `getCartItems` and if it is `Null` and than if `addToCart` is called than we perform `some action`
2. if there is `content` in the cart 
   and `addToCart` is called than `some action`,so basically here we need to check the current state of cart and that is obtained by calling `getCartItems` and check if it is `Null` or not and than if `addToCart` is called than we perform `some action` if we had some content in the cart.
3. if there is `content` in the cart 
   and `removeFromCart` is called `some action`, so basically here we need to check the current state of cart and that is obtained by calling `getCartItems` and if it is not Null and if `removeFromCart` is called than we perform `some action`

Pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
    if there is no content in cart 
        and addToCart is called than 
        $(document).track(
            );

    if there is content in the cart 
        and addToCart is called than
        $(document).track(
            );

    if there is content in the cart 
        and removeFromCart is called 
        $(document).track(
            );
```

My basic concern is that am complete newbie to jQuery and JavaScript and so am not sure how can I implement if...else logic and how can I call a function using jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: So are you simply asking how to "implement if...else logic and how can I call a funtion using jQuery/JavaScript", or to write your code for you?

Comment: if(...){}else if(...){}else{}? If logic is JS's not Jquery's.

Comment: It's in jquery, and so not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Why would it matter if there was already content in the cart? If there is no content, add item to cart, now there is one item. If there are 4 items in the cart, add item to cart, now there are 5 items. Do the same thing regardless of previous state. I think your issue is with your actual logic. Instead of re-calculating the cart each time, just have a variable: `myCart` which is a basic JS object, and have it created at the start (empty), and add and remove without concern of it the cart exists or has content.

Comment: @Anthony: I understand but for report generation from Omniture side, we have this requirement and I agree it does not make sense but somehow Omniture generates better reports based on this input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to any other programming language.

```
if() {
    ..
}
else if() {
    ..
}
else if() {
    ..
}
```

However, since these actions have to be performed when `addToCart` and `removeFromCart` are called, a simple solution is to put those conditions inside the functions itself:

```
addToCart: function(offer_id) {
    // add to cart is called and cart IS empty
    if(this.getCartItems().length == 0) {

    }
    // add to cart is called and cart is NOT empty
    else {

    }
}

removeFromCart: function(target, event) {
    // remove was called and cart has items
    if(this.getCartItems().length > 0) {

    }
}
```